# Итерация по списку словарей python

Tags: python

Добрый день помогите пожалуйста с заданием. Нужно написать программу, которая будет:

1. Получать фотографии с профиля. Для этого нужно использовать метод photos.get.
   фотографии должны быть максимального размера(ширина/высота в пикселях). В результате я получаю структуру в виде списка состоящую из словарей. Максимальный размер находится по ключу 'sizes',  последний элемент с ключом 'url'. Короче мне нужно получить все ссылки на фото максимальных размеров. Я не могу могу обратиться к значениям этих ключей.
   Вот мой код:

````
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/'
    def __init__(self, token, version):
        self.params = {
            'access_token': token,
            'v': version     
        }

    def get_photos(self, vk_id):

        # Получение фотографии с профиля с использованием метода photos.get

        photos_get_url = self.url + 'photos.get'

        params = {
            'owner_id' : vk_id,
            'album_id' : 'profile',
            'rev' : 0,
            'extended' : 1,
            'photo_sizes' : 0,
            'count' : 20
        }

        res = requests.get(photos_get_url, params={**self.params, **params}).json()
        result = res['response']['items']
        for i in result:
            for key in i.items():
                print(key)```

На выходе получается список res['response']['items'] который состоит из словарей вида :
[{'album_id': -6,
  'can_comment': 1,
  'comments': {'count': 2},
  'date': 1562944607,
  'has_tags': False,
  'id': 457239018,
  'likes': {'count': 17, 'user_likes': 1},
  'owner_id': 552934290,
  'post_id': 1,
  'reposts': {'count': 0},
  'sizes': [{'height': 130,
             'type': 'm',
             'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/sPtke3HEZH4N0qpdrjtD_YfLr0ZfEJ4G5W-GHF-gRMTTgJ2s1au_WBIaJQY_xfgEUnl3fiGj.jpg?size=130x130&quality=96&type=album',
             'width': 130},
            {'height': 130,
             'type': 'o',
             'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/sPtke3HEZH4N0qpdrjtD_YfLr0ZfEJ4G5W-GHF-gRMTTgJ2s1au_WBIaJQY_xfgEUnl3fiGj.jpg?size=130x130&quality=96&type=album',
             'width': 130},
            {'height': 200,
             'type': 'p',
             'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/vFzvg97YsENgEeiKh4x6UwQLW7jFO-JGRE397T0tsVp32c-EbXWwcFVkaw6QEPqds5GKRQSN.jpg?size=200x200&quality=96&type=album',
             'width': 200},
            {'height': 320,
             'type': 'q',
             'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/KTTtg5DnD39esdAXDbCnLMROseX4VoZzXcG9ZF8ILVZKlHf9gGhjP2YpAlP_HZGtIaT5ZVPi.jpg?size=320x320&quality=96&type=album',
             'width': 320},
            {'height': 400,
             'type': 'r',
             'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/Ewp6frruZjG76BgnZ74s9Zu0stqInLHNRbTrp0REiXLRZEq8qcZtSwXNjciM8WEEgPCUgiwM.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&type=album',
             'width': 400},
            {'height': 75,
             'type': 's',
             'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/v0EYlkR85w6UiE0gY5nurlWH4wNih1cCD8a-8rx0YwNIFyNk7ZEvPuHuTzO84ioRHMdOX8Sm.jpg?size=75x75&quality=96&type=album',
             'width': 75},
            {'height': 400,
             'type': 'x',
             'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/Ewp6frruZjG76BgnZ74s9Zu0stqInLHNRbTrp0REiXLRZEq8qcZtSwXNjciM8WEEgPCUgiwM.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&type=album',
             'width': 400}],
  'tags': {'count': 0},
  'text': ''},
````

Comment: А какая будет больше 400x300 или 250x800? Или тупо площадь считаем?

Comment: Как я понимаю нужен url с самой большой фоткой. Так?

Comment: да с самой большой. Она на последнем месте стоит

Answer (score 0):

```py
from typing import Dict, Any, List
from pprint import pprint

data = [{'album_id': -6,
         'can_comment': 1,
         'comments': {'count': 2},
         'date': 1562944607,
         'has_tags': False,
         'id': 457239018,
         'likes': {'count': 17, 'user_likes': 1},
         'owner_id': 552934290,
         'post_id': 1,
         'reposts': {'count': 0},
         'sizes': [{'height': 130,
                    'type': 'm',
                    'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/sPtke3HEZH4N0qpdrjtD_YfLr0ZfEJ4G5W-GHF-gRMTTgJ2s1au_WBIaJQY_xfgEUnl3fiGj.jpg?size=130x130&quality=96&type=album',
                    'width': 130},
                   {'height': 130,
                    'type': 'o',
                    'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/sPtke3HEZH4N0qpdrjtD_YfLr0ZfEJ4G5W-GHF-gRMTTgJ2s1au_WBIaJQY_xfgEUnl3fiGj.jpg?size=130x130&quality=96&type=album',
                    'width': 130},
                   {'height': 200,
                    'type': 'p',
                    'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/vFzvg97YsENgEeiKh4x6UwQLW7jFO-JGRE397T0tsVp32c-EbXWwcFVkaw6QEPqds5GKRQSN.jpg?size=200x200&quality=96&type=album',
                    'width': 200},
                   {'height': 320,
                    'type': 'q',
                    'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/KTTtg5DnD39esdAXDbCnLMROseX4VoZzXcG9ZF8ILVZKlHf9gGhjP2YpAlP_HZGtIaT5ZVPi.jpg?size=320x320&quality=96&type=album',
                    'width': 320},
                   {'height': 400,
                    'type': 'r',
                    'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/Ewp6frruZjG76BgnZ74s9Zu0stqInLHNRbTrp0REiXLRZEq8qcZtSwXNjciM8WEEgPCUgiwM.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&type=album',
                    'width': 400},
                   {'height': 75,
                    'type': 's',
                    'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/v0EYlkR85w6UiE0gY5nurlWH4wNih1cCD8a-8rx0YwNIFyNk7ZEvPuHuTzO84ioRHMdOX8Sm.jpg?size=75x75&quality=96&type=album',
                    'width': 75},
                   {'height': 400,
                    'type': 'x',
                    'url': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/Ewp6frruZjG76BgnZ74s9Zu0stqInLHNRbTrp0REiXLRZEq8qcZtSwXNjciM8WEEgPCUgiwM.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&type=album',
                    'width': 400}],
         'tags': {'count': 0},
         'text': ''}]

def max_size_photo(items: List[Dict[str, Any]]):
    params: dict = max(items, key=lambda x: x.get('height', 0) * x.get('width', 0))
    return params.get('url')

def post_with_max_photo(item: Dict[str, Any]):
    item.update(
        photo=max_size_photo(item.pop('sizes'))
    )
    return item

for elem in data:
    pprint(
        post_with_max_photo(
            elem
        )
    )
```

---

output

```
{'album_id': -6,
 'can_comment': 1,
 'comments': {'count': 2},
 'date': 1562944607,
 'has_tags': False,
 'id': 457239018,
 'likes': {'count': 17, 'user_likes': 1},
 'owner_id': 552934290,
 'photo': 'https://sun9-28.userapi.com/s/v1/if1/Ewp6frruZjG76BgnZ74s9Zu0stqInLHNRbTrp0REiXLRZEq8qcZtSwXNjciM8WEEgPCUgiwM.jpg?size=400x400&quality=96&type=album',
 'post_id': 1,
 'reposts': {'count': 0},
 'tags': {'count': 0},
 'text': ''}
```

> По хорошему еще бы и на quality умножить )